# How can i extract certain lines surrounding the pattern without the help of grep -A/-B/-C as these options are not present in my unix system

Tags: unix

My actual file looks like this

```
_Connecting_to_node_sgsgdsgdg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_sdgfsdgg_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sdfsdgsdg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgsdgsdgg_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgsgsgg_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sdgsdgsg_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgsgsd_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_sdggdfsgdf_
_Connecting_to_node_ggergerg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_sggergrg_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sdgegdfg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgdfggdfg_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgsgeg_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sdgsgeg_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgsdghdfhdf_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_afsdgdf_
_Connecting_to_node_afeterdfg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_asdfsdgs_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sdgega_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sdgsgdgd_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sdfsdgtg_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgsgg_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgsgtrt_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_gbdfgsdfg_
_Connecting_to_node_afsdf_......_Please_wait_
_Node_dfasfdasf_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sdgfsdggf_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgdsdgg_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sdfgsdgsdfgv_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_dgsdgsdgz_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgfsdgdfg_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_sdfsdgtsdgg_
_Connecting_to_node_sgsgsg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_sdgsgdg_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sgsdfgdfg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sdfsgdfg_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sdgsgdfg_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_asfdsdbvgdfb_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_dfsdvdfg_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_asfsdvdfv_
_Connecting_to_node_sgfsgdfg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_sggvc_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sgdfvxcvb_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgdfbcfb_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgdfgdfb_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_afsdgdfg_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgsgbxcvx_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_sgdbdzsgz_
_Connecting_to_node_sgsgsg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_sgsgsg_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sbgdgfsg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgsg...._has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgsdgfdgdfg..._successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sdgsdgdfg_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sdgsdgsg_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_sggdgfdf_
_Connecting_to_node_gsdsfgdfg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_wsgdsfgbdfg_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_wgaergerg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgsdfger_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_swgsdfghgd_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_swgdfhgh_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgdgsddfg_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_wgsgdfg_
_Connecting_to_node_wgwgg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_swgsdgag_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_swdgsdfgdg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_wgsdggg_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_wsgdg_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sdgsdfgdfg_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgsdgsdfg_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_sgsdgsdfg_
_Connecting_to_node_gdgfbdf_....._Please_wait_
_Node_wsgsdfgdf_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_wsgsdgdfg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_wgfgdf_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_wsgaggf_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_wegsgg_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_wgaegheag_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_wgragfdf_
_Connecting_to_node_wgaehgaeh_....._Please_wait_
_Node_wegsg_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sgswg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sgsbgzgbd_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sbdfbdbn_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sgbsgsf_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sdfbdfb_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_rgdfbg_
_Connecting_to_node_sgsdfbg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_rbgdfb_login_successful_
_Script_has_failed._Please_try_again_later.
_Connecting_to_node_fbdfb_....._Please_wait_
_Node_sdgvsghg_login_successful_
_Script_has_failed._Please_try_again_later.
_Connecting_to_node_bfdbd6_....._Please_wait_
_Node_fsddf.sdg_login_successful_
_DIAGUSER_password_generated_successfully_for_node_sdgsg_
_FTP_of_script_to_node_edgfsd_has_started..._Please_wait
_FTP_of_script_to_node_sdvfd_successful.
_Found_no_entry_for_changing_permissions_of_S60_sync.sh
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_sdgv16_
_Found_no_entry_for_earlier_script_
_Rundeamons_changed_in_node_97.avsdv_
_Script_execution_has_been_succesfully_completed.
_Exiting_the_node_aegf_
_Connecting_to_node_sbvdf_....._Please_wait_
........
```

My search keyword is "failed" and i want to copy that line along with the upper two lines of the file to another file
Also my unix system does'nt support the grep -A/-B/-C options how can i do this...... Please help...

Comment: What do you have? sed, awk, perl, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed` script:

```
:loop
/failed/{
s/^\(.*\n\)\([^\n]\+\n\)\([^\n]\+\n\)\(.*failed.*\)$/\2\3\4/
p;
d;
}
N;
b loop
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# sed -n -f  sample.sed file.txt
_Connecting_to_node_sgsdfbg_....._Please_wait_
_Node_rbgdfb_login_successful_
_Script_has_failed._Please_try_again_later.
_Connecting_to_node_fbdfb_....._Please_wait_
_Node_sdgvsghg_login_successful_
_Script_has_failed._Please_try_again_later.
```

Comment: Friend this is not working :-( . I am getting the same result as that of my original file.

Comment: can you tell your OS and sed version? Because, It is working fine for me. I am using Debian(Linux) and GNU sed version 4.2.1 .